# How to get an excel Workbook/sheet to be in focus?

Tags: excel, vba, barcode-scanner

Ok, So I'm trying to use a barcode scanner for several purposes and I have this issue where, if someone uses the pc where this scanner is awaiting a scan to a workbook, the workbook loses focus.  I want to set a timer where it checks or sets the focus for the workbook for a set time interval.  The problem is as follows;

[Not in focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veaeP.png)

[In focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xedr.png)

From the images above, the workbook will only accept input while in the state of the second image (where the icons are not ghosted)

I've tried a variety of different methods to restore the workbook to the un-ghosted form such as;

```
'ThisFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'AppActivate (ThisFile)
'Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
'Windows("Book1").Activate
'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = x
'Application.WindowState = xlNormal
'Application.SendKeys "~", True
'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Activate
'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
'AppActivate ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption
'Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:0:30"), "ActivateExcel"
'AppActivate Application.Caption
```

I've also tried one of Chip Pearson's solutions with no luck there either.
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ActivateExcelMain.aspx

I'm out of solutions. (and ways to describe the issue for searches)

What I need is for the sheet to become active without having to physically click the workbook, and accept input for the cell that is awaiting the input.

I realize I could achieve this likely with a form (though I'm not sure about focus there either) but I have other issues to solve there before I can implement that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `AppActivate` uses the Windows Title text, not just the filename. So, try: `AppActivate "<file name>.xls - Excel", 1`. If you have trouble getting the Title bar name, use `ALT-TAB` to see all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  It still doesn't activate the window to the state I need it.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being downvoted...Here's something that works for me.
It continuously activates the workbook no matter what else is clicked in Windows. If the Excel state is not what you're looking for then you're probably focused in VBA or a cell is in edit mode.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliSeconds As Long)

Sub test()

    Do
    
        AppActivate "Book1 - Excel", 1
        DoEvents
        Sleep 2000
    
    Loop


End Sub
```

PS. This is not a good idea.

Comment: Nick,  I appreciate you responding and trying to help and I hope you don't get down voted.  I don't understand why that would happen, you're trying to help.  I copy/pasted your code exactly in a new WB just to be exact.  It still doesn't work from me.  I run the macro and then click the desktop and the workbook never regains focus. It's truly baffling.  All I want is to simulate ALT/TAB, which works perfectly, but VBA just doesn't play nice.  Is it a windows issue?  I just don't know. I'm using W11.